# How can I use the data of an activity in another activity?

Tags: java, android, sms, send, android-contacts

I want to send an SMS with location to the contact that the user has been saved. But I don't know how to do it. I am totally new to Android Studio, so I don´t know how to write my code that it will work the way I want it.
Please, can you help me to do that?

This is the code of sending SMS:

```
Button sendBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    });

}

protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            // fixme: show explanation
            // before requesting the permission again
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    } else {
        sendSmsImpl();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sendSmsImpl();
            } else {
                // fixme: explain that it can't send SMS without the permission
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // !!! NOTE: you still need break inside switch/case
            // even with curly braces
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void sendSmsImpl() {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("+212xxx", null, "Je suis en danger, voici ma localisation : https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=<lat>,<lng>", null, null);
    //todo: use sentIntent argument of sendTextMessage to detect success/error
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And this the code of saving contact:

```
private int id;

private String phoneNo;

private String name;

// constructor
public ContactModel(int id, String name, String phoneNo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.phoneNo = validate(phoneNo);
    this.name = name;
}

// validate the phone number, and reformat is necessary
private String validate(String phone) {

    // creating StringBuilder for both the cases
    StringBuilder case1 = new StringBuilder("+212");
    StringBuilder case2 = new StringBuilder("");

    // check if the string already has a "+"
    if (phone.charAt(0) != '+') {
        for (int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++) {
            // remove any spaces or "-"
            if (phone.charAt(i) != '-' && phone.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                case1.append(phone.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return case1.toString();
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++) {
            // remove any spaces or "-"
            if (phone.charAt(i) != '-' || phone.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                case2.append(phone.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return case2.toString();
    }

}

public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't appear relevant to the question. What are your two activities, and what data are you trying to send between them, and what action should trigger this behaviour?

Comment: instead of sending an sms to one predefined number, i want to send it to all numbers that the user has been saved.  First code is for send sms Activity and the seconde one is for saving contact number Activity..

Comment: The second code sample doesn't appear to be an activity. An activity is a class that extends `Activity` or `FragmentActivity` or similar and is invoked via a method like `startActivity(...)`. It looks like your activity needs a list of `ContactModel` objects, and should iterate over them to retrieve the numbers you want send an SMS to.

Comment: yes that's what i want.

Comment: Can you help me with it?